# OO Design - Delegating responsibility of results to a different class

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

I've a class which calls a service which returns makes different types of predictions. The API returns the confidence score for each label for each prediction type. Currently I call the service and then store all the scores returned by the service. However after doing some investigation, I've found that in my use case I'll need to change the thresholds for the labels returned by the service for one prediction type.

So for example: I called the service for predicting whether an image is of an animal or not and the service has two labels True or false.

```
{
  predictedValue: True,
  details: {
    True: 0.65,
    False: 0.35
  }
}
```

The predictedValue field is what the prediction service owner thinks the image is based on it's thresholds. But my results from the API indicates that unless the True confidence is greater than 0.70 it never is an animal.

```
public class PredictionResults {
    String prediction;
    Map<String, Double> details;
}
public class PredictionServiceDataLoader {
    public void getAndStorePredictionResults(String predictionType, String id) {
        PredictionResults predictionResults = getPredictionByCallingPredictionService(predictionType);
        saveResults(predictionResults, id);
    }
}
```

Now since I want to override the results returned by the service and one way of doing that is:

```
public void getAndStorePredictionResults(String predictionType, String id) {
    PredictionResults predictionResults = getPredictionByCallingPredictionService(predictionType);
    if(predictionType.equals("detectAnimal")) {
        //Override value based on threshold
        if(predictionResults.getDetails().get("True") < 0.70) {
            predictionResults.setPrediction("False");
        }
    }
    saveResults(predictionResults, id);
}
```

Now if I want to remove the responsibility of changing the results based on threshold outside PredictionServiceDataLoader then I was thinking of implementing in the following way:

```
public interface PredictionResultsOverride {
    public String getPreditionType();
    public String getPredictionResults(PredictionResults predictionResults);
}

public class AnimalPredictionResultOverride implements PredictionResultsOverride {
    @Override 
    public String getPreditionType() {
        return "detectAnimal";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPredictionResults(PredictionResults predictionResults) {
        if(predictionResults.getDetails().get("True") < 0.70) {
            predictionResults.setPrediction("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Then my PredictionServiceDataLoader will do delegate the responsibility of modifying the results to a different class in the following way:

```
public class PredictionServiceDataLoader {

    @Autowired
    private List<PredictionResultsOverride> predictionResultsImpl;
    public void getAndStorePredictionResults(String predictionType, String id) {
        PredictionResults predictionResults = getPredictionByCallingPredictionService(predictionType);
        Optional<PredictionResultsOverride> predictionResultsOverrideImpl = 
            predictionResultsImpl.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(predictionType)) 
                .findFirst();
        predictionResults = predictionResultsOverrideImpl.map(x -> x.getPredictionResults(predictionResults)).orElse(predictionResults);
        saveResults(predictionResults, id);
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to delegate the responsibility of overriding thresholds to a different class? Is there a different approach I can take? In my opinion the responsibility of PredictionServiceDataLoader class should be just to call the prediction service and store the results.

Answer (score 1):

"In my opinion the responsibility of PredictionServiceDataLoader class should be just to call the prediction service and store the results."

You are correct, PredictionServiceDataLoader, ideally, should retrieve the results and store it.

Your requirement is to override the results based on some criteria. This can be taken care just before showing it to end-users (or before using it for further processing). This way, you will have raw results stored and can be referred in case of modified overridden criteria (for ex. true should be >=80%). If you store the results after overriding it then you will have to keep additinal details (like isOverridden, criteria etc ) along with the result.

Comment: Since the details Map has the raw results I think it is ok to replace the prediction variable since that is what the service thinks the label is. Since it is a map, I can also add a field saying that this was overridden,